# UIWebView inside TabBarController causes content to go behind tab bar

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a web view inside a tab bar controller. The problem is when using the web view, the content goes behind the tab bar and I cannot scroll to the bottom of the page. How do I resolve this?

Here is how everything is setup in Xcode
[image: UIWebView inside tab bar controller]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AutoLayout set the constraints of the UIWebView so that it is attached to all the sides.

Edit: Instructions

- Select the UIWebView
- Select the icon shown in the picture below

  [image]
- Unselect the Checkbox for "Constrain to Margins" because we want to constrain to neighbor
- Set the numbers around the center square to 0's
- Click the icons that are between the middle square and the numbers you just changed
- Click Add Constraints

Comment: I am using auto-layout, but I am not very good with it. I understand alignment, but not how to "attach" to all sides. Could you give me a step by step?

Comment: I tried that and still have problem see https://www.dropbox.com/s/rxze9jn60o5gpyy/Screenshot%202014-10-15%2013.25.30.png?dl=0

Comment: I got it. I had to make the view smaller.